# Get JavaScript timezone string with DST settings

Tags: javascript, c, timezone, embedded, dst

**Context**

I'm running a web server on a ESP8266 and would like to implement automatic DST on the device. At the moment I'm getting the time settings from the client. I'm using ESP8266 SDK and not Arduino.

**Information flow**

The web server has no internet connection only WiFi.

|Web Server|<---->|WiFi|<---->|Client|<---->|internet|

How in intend to send the TZ string.

|Web Server|<--|WiFi|<--|Client|

The Client can be anything that can run a modern browser.

**Question**

Is there a way to get the DST settings from a client in the following format using JavaScript?

> std offset dst [offset],start[/time],end[/time]

I can get the timezone string using:

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone
```

The current system I'm working on does not have support for the format.

> :characters

Witch is the format that the above JavaScript returns. If I'm not mistaken.

**Code**

```
time_t now =0;
struct tm timeinfo;
setenv("TZ","IST-2IDT,M3.5.5/2,M10.5.0/2", 1);
tzset();

timeinfo.tm_sec =   sec;
timeinfo.tm_min =   min;
timeinfo.tm_hour =  hour;
timeinfo.tm_mday =  date;
timeinfo.tm_mon =   mon;
timeinfo.tm_year =  year + 100;
timeinfo.tm_wday =  weekd;

//set the time manually
now = mktime(&timeinfo);

if(now < 0){
 //handle error
 ESP_LOGE(__func__, "Time error");

}else{
 localtime_r(&now, &timeinfo);
 //print tm_isdst value
 ESP_LOGW(__func__, "DST is active %d",timeinfo.tm_isdst);

 char strftime_buf[64];
 strftime(strftime_buf, sizeof(strftime_buf), "%c", &timeinfo);
 //print time str
 ESP_LOGI(__func__, "The current date/time: %s", strftime_buf);
}
```

**Problem**

If I set the TZ veriable with `IST-2IDT,M3.5.5/2,M10.5.0/2` the `timeinfo.tm_isdst` variable changes on the expected dates and times. If I set TZ with `Asia/Jerusalem` the `timeinfo.tm_isdst` variable simply stays at 0. Also tested with `America/New_York` with the same result.

**Reference**

[TZ-Variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/TZ-Variable.html)

[Almost Identical Use Case](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/314)

The reason I'm not using the '[Almost Identical Use Case](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/314)' is because I'm seriously low on ram and storage to store large C strings on the Web Server.

Comment: Why do you want to know if it's DST?

Comment: The [tz database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) provides historical information, so `Asia/Jerusalem` and `America/New_York` are much better than `std offset dst [offset],start[/time],end[/time]` which is only valid "now". Time zone information changes all the time (and it's going to continue happening, seeing how a lot of places are shedding DST).

Comment: @ikegami. Its to generalize the code for multiple regions (in short). 
If I could use the `Asia/Jerusalem` and `America/New_York` form the tz database strings I would but as I said when I give the string to the web server (ESP8266) it gets ignored(like there is no timezone string). The idea is to use a desktop/server client that most likely has the most up to date dst settings to set the device. If the time zone information changes then the user/client will have to pass the data again.

Comment: You seem to have missed the point. There is no "most up to date dst *settings*"(assuming you mean `std offset dst [offset],start[/time],end[/time]` for setting) because the setting depends on the year of the date-time to which it's being applied.

Comment: The larger point is that you should be adding support for the tz database rather than trying to get a "setting" from a tz database name.

Comment: But that's an aside. You say the problem is that `tm_isdst` is `0`. Why do you care?

Comment: @ikegami By "most up to date dst settings" I meant whatever the setting is now on the client system. I'm just working with the cards I've been dealt...  I'm using `tm_isdst` to manually set the time forward so `if == 1` advance the time `if <= 0` do nothing.

Comment: Re "*I meant whatever the setting is now on the client system*", You can use `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone` for that, as you said.

Comment: If you're trying to generate a string to include in a page, you could always use JS on the client to do that.

Comment: @ikegami I've got the clients time and passing it on to the web-server using `Date()`. The web page currently displaying both server and client time. I was just wondering if there is a method to convert `:characters` to `std offset dst [offset],start[/time],end[/time]` before I scrap the feature.

Comment: No, it's impossible to convert `America/New_York` to `std offset dst [offset],start[/time],end[/time]`. It's like asking to asking to convert someone's work history into a job name. You could extract a job name from the work history, but that's hardly a conversion.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to generate a POSIX time zone string from a web server and send that to your device, right?  If so, [this script](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/314#issuecomment-198226333) on your web server will help.

Comment: @Matt Johnson-Pint Actually the other way around. I want to generate the POSIX on the device (basically anything that can run a modern web browser) and then send that to the web server.

Comment: Are you restricted to relying solely on the `TZ` env variable on the server? Any approach where you are using the IANA time zone name (`America/New_York`, etc.) would be more reliable.  For example, if you can use C++ you can use `tz.h/tz.cpp` from [Howard Hinnant's libraries](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable solution is to send the time as an epoch time stamp and use JavaScript to convert it to a local time.

---

That said, if you install a copy of the [tz database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database), the last time of each zone file is a POSIX TZ string (which may be empty).

Of course, you can't count on it being accurate for dates of a different year than the current year, but it seems to be what you want.

```
$ tail -n 1 /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Jerusalem
IST-2IDT,M3.4.4/26,M10.5.0

$ tail -n 1 /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York
EST5EDT,M3.2.0,M11.1.0
```

The db is ~3.5 MiB is size, but you could easily extract the information you want before placing it on your device. The following produces ~60 KiB of output.

```
perl -e'
   use strict;
   use warnings;
   use feature qw( say );

   use File::Find::Rule    qw( );
   use IPC::System::Simple qw( capturex );

   my ($db) = @ARGV
     or die("usage\n");

   for my $tz (File::Find::Rule->relative->file->in($db)) {
      my $posix = capturex("tail", -n => 1, "--", "$db/$tz");
      chomp($posix);
      say join "\t", $tz, $posix;
   }
' /usr/share/zoneinfo
```

Comment: 3.5Mb is too large. Only have 2Mb free left at the moment of total of 4Mb. I'm on a microcontroller. Yes the `tail` output is exactly what I want.